# rtabmap: stereo outdoor mapping

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all, My ubuntu is 14.04 and i am using ROS indigo.i work off line. i take left and right images from two web-cams and save these to file. I would like run demo_stereo_outdoor.launch from tutorials of rtabmap_ros package for my image file. i am new in ros and rtabmap and don't know how to create rosbag from my image file.
please help me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272514/rtabmap:-stereo-outdoor-mapping/) by [zahra.zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32018/zahra.zahra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may use `stereo_sequence_publisher.py` from [bag_tools](https://github.com/srv/srv_tools/tree/kinetic/bag_tools/scripts) package to stream left/right images with their corresponding `camera_info` on ROS. There is an example here with rtabmap and some stereo images: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Stereo-mapping#process-a-directory-of-stereo-images-in-ros

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0